# Is my change of variables of a PDE correct?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've calculated a lot and checked the first derivatives with wolframalpha. Still I'm not sure if I have done everything correctly, could someone have a look please?

Original PDE:
\begin{align*}
u_t- \frac{\lambda}{2}u_{zz}=0
\end{align*}
New coordinate:
\begin{align*}
y_i=\frac{1}{\pi} \arctan(\gamma z+c)+\frac{1}{2}
\Leftrightarrow z=\frac{\tan(\frac{1}{2}(2 \pi y- \pi))-c}{\gamma}
\end{align*}
First derivatives:
\begin{align*}
y_z= \frac{\gamma}{\pi((c+\gamma z)^2+1)}\\
z_y=-\frac{2 \pi}{\gamma (\cos(2 \pi y)-1)}
\end{align*}
u differentiated using chaining rule, derivation of differential operators:
\begin{align*}
u_z=u_y y_z=u_y \frac{\gamma}{\pi((c+\gamma z)^2+1)}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial z}= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\gamma}{\pi((c+\gamma z)^2+1)} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
u_y= u_z z_y = u_z (-\frac{2 \pi}{\gamma (\cos(2 \pi y)-1)})\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (-\frac{2 \pi}{\gamma (\cos(2 \pi y)-1)})
\end{align*}
To ease notiation
\begin{align*}
A:= y_z= \frac{\gamma}{\pi((c+\gamma z)^2+1)}.
\end{align*}
2nd derivative using product rule:
\begin{align*}
u_{zz} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z} u_z = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (u_y \frac{\gamma_i}{\pi((c+\gamma z)^2+1)})\\
&=A(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(u_y A))
=A(u_{yy} A+u_yA_y)=A(u_{yy}A+u_y\cdot 0)=A^2 u_{yy}
\end{align*}
Inserting into original PDE:
\begin{align*}
u_t- \frac{\lambda}{2}A^2 u_{yy}=0
\Leftrightarrow u_t - \frac{\lambda}{2} (\frac{\gamma}{\pi((c+\gamma z)^2+1)})^2 u_{yy}=0
\end{align*}
Now $z=\frac{\tan(\frac{1}{2}(2 \pi y- \pi))-c}{\gamma}$ should be inserted into the equation.

Thank you in advance! 
Nina

Comment: I've at least displayed the image on the same page, but if you wrote it in $\LaTeX$ you'll find you can easily copy the code here, between `$...$` or `$$...$$` for displayed formulas. This isn't foolproof since MathJax isn't $\LaTeX$, but what you've written looks compatible. On a different matter, I'm curious as to why you would use this change of variables?

Comment: Thanks for editing my Post.  The computational domain of the original equation is unbounded and I want to avoid using artificial boundaries, so I want to map it to (0,1).   I've tried to copy my latex into the post with dollardollar...dollardollar, but it doesn't recognize the align-environments, so if that's not somehow against the rules I would just keep it as a picture.

Comment: It's much preferable to post it as code because image links can break, and also it just looks nicer! Why don't you edit the plain code in? I might be able to make it work (but while I'm doing so I'll rollback the edit to the image version so people can still see the question).

Comment: Didn't know it would just work like that :)   Seems to be fine now, I've deleted the picture. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay now another question, what are the sub-indices $i$ for? Do you have more than just $(t,z)$ as variables?

Comment: z is actually a vector, i should have put $z_i$ everywhere in the equations.   So there's only t and z as variables for this equation. I happen to have other equations where I need other components of z and that is some kind of leftover. I'll remove the subindices.

Comment: You made a mistake, where you said $A_y=0$, because while your expression only depends on $z$, $z$ in turn does depend on $y$.